# Duplicating a project and changing its name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was creating a new project that is a copy of another project. The thing is that when I want to rename the project, some connection problems appear when I want to execute my app. Can someone tell me a good way to replace all the names of the old project? The classe names are the same in the new one, so I don't have to change them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently and it was a straightforward process.

I suggest you start again. Make a copy of the project then click twice slowly on the project name in the project navigator. You can then rename the project.

Xcode then suggests which files/resources to change - you can accept all changes or amend if you like.

Once complete your project will build and run with no problems.

Comment: The things is that when I do this, there are some targets that xcode does not change... I select them, click rename but tells me: "New name for file cannot be same as old name "name"

Comment: I was changing all the names, and now I have problems with the "Prefix.pch"

Comment: Goto Build Settings for your target - search for "GCC_PREF" - check the value and ensure it is the same name as your .pch file

Comment: It says: "name of project"/prefix.pch (in adhoc, debug, release and header)